# Runtime of slice operation in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how slicing works in Python. If I do something like

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr[0:n] = [9]*n
```

What is the runtime of a splice operation where n is some integer? Does this this run in O(n), or is slicing somehow constant time?

Comment: All this does is multiply 9 by `n` and then raise an exception, so its runtime is constant.

Comment: @ChrisMartin very funny, thanks for pointing this out. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the IPython notebook and it's `%%timeit magic` which makes timing things easy.  I think I understand what you're trying to do, so I sliced a list of 500 elements vs. 5000 a list of 500 elements.  Is this what you ahd in mind?

[image]

Unless my analysis is wrong, this looks order N?

Comment: Your analysis is wrong. You're timing the creation of `arr`, not just the replacement of n of its elements.

(that being said, both are O(n))

Comment: Thanks, I will correct it, but OP should be able to do this trivially with %%timeit in the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that's constant. The expression `[9]*n` alone is linear in space, and therefore also in time.